# How to fix " '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Tags: c++

I am trying to run a cpp file using `./a.out` but after compiling it simply returns that error.

I just routed `C:\cygwin64\bin` to the `PATH` environment variable to get g++ working but now `./` is not functioning as expected.

Comment: `./` doesn't work in cmd.exe.

Comment: What about if I am trying to run something in CLion? I have been running files using ./ on CLion on MacOS. Currently using Windows.

Comment: use the parameter `-o a.exe` when compiling and then simply write `a.exe` to run it.

Comment: "I have been running files using ./ on CLion on MacOS." MacOS is not Windows and Windows is not MacOS.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Apologies for the naivety of the question. The assistance is much appreciated.